# How long does the SYLDA fairing stay in orbit after deploying?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, fairings, ariane

For dual-manifest missions, Ariane 5 often uses the Système de Lancement Double or SYLDA system to encapsulate the lower of two stacked satellites. It can be seen in the following image encapsulating the Planck spacecraft.

[image]

This fairing is separated after the first satellite, placed above, has been separated. Therefore, it separates in whatever the target orbit is.

How long does it take for this fairing to reenter? It seems like it might take a very, very long time.

Comment: Ariane-5 rocket launches satellites and Sylda fairing to "geostationary transfer orbit". It's not the final orbit, satellites boost themselves to geostationary orbit after separation. Silda's orbit (as well as the orbit of Ariane upper stage) have high apogee up to 35000 km, but low perigee about 200 km. Because of this Silda's orbit decays by atmospheric friction at perigee.

Comment: I asked related question about upper stages https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33213/25911

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is typical lifetime of GTO rocket stages before reentry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33213/what-is-typical-lifetime-of-gto-rocket-stages-before-reentry)